# What is the highest version of nuGet packages/MS Libraries for IdentityServer3

Tags: identityserver3

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and starting up with IdentityServer3.  From reading as much as I could find, this version requires Katana and Owin 1.0.  Some of the MS Libraries and nuGet tools introduced breaking changes however.

I am not ready to dive into .Net Code or IdentityServer4 at this time.  However, following the instructions from Scott Brady's work I cannot get IdentityServer3 working in my MVC application.  TokenValidationParameters has a breaking change.

How should I proceed?  Does one of my packages need to be downgraded?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.7" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.16.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.4.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="5.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

The affected code:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> ValidateIdentityTokenAsync(string token, string state)
{
    const string certString = "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";

    var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certString));

    var result = await this.Request
        .GetOwinContext()
        .Authentication
        .AuthenticateAsync("TempCookie");

    if (result == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("No temp cookie");
    }

    if (state != result.Identity.FindFirst("state").Value)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("invalid state");
    }

    var parameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidAudience = "implicitclient",
        ValidIssuer = IdServBaseUri,
        IssuerSigningKeys = new X509SecurityToken(cert)
    };

    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken jwt;
    var id = handler.ValidateToken(token, parameters, out jwt);

    if (id.FindFirst("nonce").Value != result.Identity.FindFirst("nonce").Value)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid nonce");
    }

    this.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut("TempCookie");

    return id.Claims;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a bit of digging and experimenting.  Here's the gist.

1. Make sure you have no reference to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens (remove the package if you have it).
2. Make sure you downgrade to
   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt v4.x (removes the dependency on #1).
3. Add a reference to System.IdentityModel (for SecurityToken & JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken)